# How can I use a regex expression to identify the falses between braces on different lines?

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to use the Python re.sub module to replace any instance of false in the example below with "false, \n"

```
local Mission = {

    start_done = false
    game_over = false

} --End Mission
```

I've attempted the following, but I'm not getting a successful replacements. The idea being I start and end with the anchor strings, skip over anything that isn't a "false", and return "false + ','" when I get a match. Any help would be appreciated!

```
re.sub(r'(Mission = {)(.+?)(false)(.+?)(} --End Mission)', r'\1' + ',' + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'Mission = {.*?} --End Mission', lambda x: x.group().replace('false', 'false, \n'), text, flags=re.S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ7mKm/1).

*Notes*:

- The `Mission = {.*?} --End Mission` regex matches `Mission = {`, then any zero or more chars as few as chars, and then `} --End Mission`
- Then `false` is replaced with `false, \n` in the matched texts.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/q1Dnkm):

```py
import re
text = 'local Mission = {\n    start_done = false\n    game_over = false\n\n} --End Mission'
rx = r'Mission = {.*?} --End Mission'
print(re.sub(rx, lambda x: x.group().replace('false', 'false, \n'), text, flags=re.S))
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the reasoning for using a lamba expression?

Comment: @johnsnow69 Because to change the matches inline, you need to access the match value, and it is not possible without a callable.

Comment: you forgot an `\n` in the `text`: `text = 'local Mission = {\n\n`...

Answer (score 0):

Another option without regex:

```
your_string = 'local Mission = {\n    start_done = false\n    game_over = false\n\n} --End Mission'
print(your_string.replace(' = false\n', ' = false,\n'))
```

Output:

```
local Mission = {
    start_done = false,
    game_over = false,

} --End Mission
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that every "false" string which is preceded by `=`  and followed by `\n` has to be substituted then here a regex:

```
re.sub(r'= (false)\n', r'= \1,\n', text)
```

Note: you introduce 5 groups in your regex so you should have used `\3` and not `\1` to refer to "false", group start from 1, see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) at paragraph *`\number`*